# Convert SQL bit datatype to 1 or 0 in C# code

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

With Entity Framework from SQL I am accessing a field that its schema says "`bit`"
Now I want to put it in C# code in an `int`
I wrote something like this: Is this correct? or there are other ways?

```
int myResult = Convert.ToInt32(ef.thatField);
```

Comment: Why do you want it as an `int` instead of a `bool`?

Comment: Bit maps to boolean, so `Convert.ToInt32(someBoolean);` should work fine.

Comment: @Bobson because requirements says so!

Comment: @DevWannaBe - Strange, but ok.  Can't argue with the reqs.

Comment: Sometimes the `bit` can be mapped to `bool?` instead of `bool`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you can try this :

```
    int myResult = ef.thatField ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: The OP's example will work, but this is better because it's more explicit about what's happening.

Comment: yeah .. it follows the rule "Always keep it simple" @Bobson

Comment: Sometimes the `bit` can be mapped to `bool?` instead of `bool`. In this case you can caught the runtime exception.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan the developer should be aware of it , i think in his question he didn't mention the case that this column may accept nulls

Comment: He didn't mention that it can't.

Comment: in this case he could use ef.thatField.Value

Comment: Have you used `Value` of nullable with null value?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - If the column is nullable, then the OP needs to tell us what a `NULL` maps to.  After all, he isn't trying to cast it to `int?`.